# convert dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in php

Tags: php, date, date-format

I tried the following code to change the dateformat from dmy to ymd, but when using i got wrong dates.

My code

```
$sdate11=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["txtstartdates"]) );
$sdate111=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["txtenddates"]) );
```

dates inserted were

```
30-05-2013 and  31-05-2013
```

the date it returned was

```
2035-11-03 and 2036-11-02
```

could you please help me to find what was the problem here and solve it

Thank you.

Comment: In what format is the dates in $_POST["txtstartdates"] and $_POST["txtenddates"]?

Comment: The format seems correct. Check the values of $_POST["txtstartdates"] and$_POST["txtenddates"]

Comment: you are getting `2036-11-02` that is already `yyyy-mm-dd`. What's your problem now?

Comment: what does your $_POST["txtstartdates"] has??

Comment: check the edited question i have added the dates entered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with **split** like

```
$a = split('-',$_POST["txtstartdates"]);
```

or you can use explode even like

```
$a = explode('-',$_POST["txtstartdates"]);
$my_new_date = $a[2].'-'.$a[1].'-'.$a[0];
```

Here strtotime will not work for the format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) is more reliable. For [`split()`](http://php.net/split) there is a message: `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Answer (score 4):

You might use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) for that:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['txtstartdates']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['txtenddates']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the DateTime object to convert the date into the format you want?

```
$DateTime = new DateTime($_POST['FIELD']);
echo $DateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct , I dont know why its not working for you Can you try below
I have made the `''` from `""` only

```
$sdate11=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['txtstartdates']));
$sdate111=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['txtenddates']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using single line as:

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateInput)->format('Y-m-d');
```